# Free alternative to ArcGIS World Geocoding Service for reverse geocoding

Tags: software-recommendations, reverse-geocoding

I'm seeking a free alternative to ArcGIS World Geocoding Service for running geoprocessing tool Reverse Geocode in ArcGIS Pro. All feature types provided in the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service would be ideal

Comment: What feature types are provided in the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service?

Answer (score 5):

Most services have a **free option with specified limit**, prices often are changing but here are some options for 2020:

1. [Batch geocoder for journalists](https://geocode.localfocus.nl/) - **free** batch geocoder for small data samples
2. **[OSM Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/)** - free 1 request per second (**one of the really free services**)
3. [HERE Geocoding](https://developer.here.com/products/geocoding-and-search) - free 250k records limit per month
4. [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) - free 40k records limit per month (**taking 200$ free per month**)
5. [MapQuest Geocoding API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/geocoding-api/) - free 15k records limit per month
6. [positionstack](https://positionstack.com/) - free 25k records limit per month
7. [LocationIQ](https://locationiq.com) - free 5k records limit per day
8. [Geocod](https://www.geocod.io/pricing/) - free 2,5k records limit per day
9. [Carto Geocoding](https://carto.com/help/working-with-data/geocoding/) - free 400 records limit per month
10. **[Mapbox Geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/) - free 100k records** limit per month
11. [Opencagedata](https://opencagedata.com/api) - free 2,5k records limit per day
12. [Bing Geocoding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/) - free 125k records per month (crazy pricing, hard to find...)
13. [ESRI ArcGIS Geocoding](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/geocoding/) - free 1,2k limit records per month (another crazy pricing, [better look at their table](https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/credits/))

Great tool for using some of the services is **FME**, [look at their Geocoder transformer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/geocoder.htm#Geocoding_Services).

There are also a number of **national services limited only to one country**, and it seems not to have any geocoding record limits, here you have [a link to USA census.gov service](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/) and [Polish GUGiK service for example](https://capap.gugik.gov.pl/app/geokodowanie/index.html).

Comment: Most of the above services have data restrictions that don't let you legally store the results of your geocodes. Do any of the above not have that restriction?

Comment: @DavidGalt I don't see such restriction in OSM Nominatim policies for example: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/